# Django-Getting most recent entry before today

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the most recent entry before today's date.  I tried to go about it like this:

```
query = my_table.objects.filter(~Q(date__gt=datetime.date.today()))
recent = query[-1]
```

However it doesn't allow negative splicing.  I'm not quite sure the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order the queryset by date in reverse order and then get the first record:

```
recent = my_table.objects.filter(date__lt=datetime.date.today()) \
                         .order_by('-date').first()
```

Or you can use the [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) method but it will raise `DoesNotExist` in case if there is no such record in database (`first()` in this case will return `None`):

```
recent = my_table.objects.filter(date__lt=datetime.date.today()) \
                         .latest('date')
```

Comment: I was trying the 2nd one and i get "object has no attribute 'query'"

Comment: What happens when you try the first option?